# Sound becomes quiet when launching games/apps

Tags: audio

Everytime I launch an app like Skype, or any game, the sound becomes extremely quiet and poor quality. I've seen all the other questions about this topic, but none of the answers there helped.

OS: Windows 10
Audio drivers/devices: Nvidia Virtual Audio Device (Wave Extensible) (WDM), Realtek High Definition Audio

All of my drivers are updated, I've turned off the settings where Windows lowers the sound of other apps when you are using Skype. I've turned off the option that allows apps taking the priority of the sound and making other quiet.

I should also mention that I have Dolby Digital Plus which turns off by itself sometimes. (The sound quality without Dolby becomes worse and quieter)

If I launch a game and I have background music in my browser (Chrome), I'll need to disable the Realtek device, then active it again and, sometimes I'll have to turn on and Dolby Digital Plus.

Comment: I believe Skype also has options to attenuate volume. Just to confirm, are these the settings you've said you've already checked? 1 - Control Panel, Sound, (right click a Playback device) Properties, Advanced, `(uncheck) Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device` 2 - Control Panel, Sound, Communications - `Do Nothing`

Comment: Yes, they are all unchecked. I would also like to add that when I start a game, for example GTA 5, the Dolby Digital Plus turns off and I have to turn it manually on for the sound to become normal again.